# How to convert string of data into format with quotations?

Tags: string-manipulation, formatting

How would I be able to convert a single string to a string of data? An example would be converting:

```
data= AMD AAPL FB SNAP MSFT
```

into the format:

```
{"AMD","AAPL","FB","SNAP","MSFT"}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
data = "AMD AAPL FB SNAP MSFT";

StringSplit[data]
```

> {"AMD", "AAPL", "FB", "SNAP", "MSFT"}

Comment: thanks again eldo! Also realized to add `InputForm` to add the "" between each string. Thanks a lot :)